# Узнать position в Adapter

Tags: android

Имеется следующий код:

```
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
       layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout, container, false);
       ImageView imageView = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
       TextView textView_description = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.textViewDescription);
       TextView textView_title = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.textView_title);
       TextView text_hide_cancel_reserve = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.text_hide_cancel_reserve);

       ImageView imageViewShowPresent = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.reserved_null);

       imageView.setImageResource(image_resources[position]);

       textView_description.setText(text_resources[position]);
       textView_title.setText(text_resources_title[position]);
       text_hide_cancel_reserve.setText(text_hide_cancel_reserve_array[position]);
       imageViewShowPresent.setImageResource(image_reserved[position]);
       PagerNumber = position;
       Log.d(TAG, "PagerNumber " + PagerNumber);
       container.addView(item_view);
       return item_view;
    }
```

Как получить реальный номер страницы в `адаптере`? 
Потому что при отсчете назад (и иногда и вперед) в логах происходят сдвиги (то на одну, то на две позиции)?

Answer (score 1):

Адаптер работает немного не так, как вы себе представляете. Он заранее подготавливает не только текущую страницу, но так же и соседние. Поэтому идет, как вы это называете, *сдвиг*. Если вам нужно получить номер страницы в какой-то конкретный момент времени (например по клику на кнопку), то спросите его у пейджера

```
vewPager.getCurrentItem()
```

Если же нужно всегда иметь номер страницы под рукой в какой-нибудь переменной, то нужно установить listener

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        PagerNumber = position;
    }
});
```

Comment: Студия не может определить viewPager. Как мне его нужно декларировать, чтобы работало? У меня еще viewGroup container , если это имеет значение.

Comment: забыл отметить.

Comment: @user186295, вы привели фрагмент кода из адаптера ко ViewPager? Вот этот viewpager и используйте

Comment: куда именно этот код вставить? Имею в виду, после какого метода или в каком-то отдельном методе?

Comment: @user186295, там, где вы используете ваш адаптер.