# Неправильная позиция при нажатии кнопки

Tags: android

Есть 2 Activity:
1. SixActivity
2. CustomSwipeAdapter

В SixActivity есть pagerAdapter на часть экрана и кнопка (выполняет функцию брони при помощи Parse.com).
В Apater - показываются 10 фотографий, описание к ним, название каждой фотографии.

В чем вопрос: каждый раз, как я перематываю вперед содержимое адаптера, он показывает правильную страницу (ПРАКТИЧЕСКИ всегда), когда перематываю назад - происходит какой-то ужас, номера страниц могут идти в перемешку, могут чередоваться.. В общем - неправильно. 
Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/453228/%D0%A3%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-position-%D0%B2-adapter) мне подсказали, в чем проблема, но решение я так и не могу применить. Не понимаю, как и где именно я должен его реализовать. 
Прошу мне подробно разъяснить, где и в чем я ошибаюсь и как решить мою проблему, чтобы при нажатии кнопки в SixActivity, бронь выполнялась только на нужной фотографии и странице.

Код моего CustomSwipeAdapter:

```
public class CustomSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
static String Button_hide_text = "00000000000000000000000000000";
static String Button_show_text = "10";
String number_page;
private int[] image_resources = {R.drawable/*.....*/};
private static int[] image_reserved_wish = {R.drawable/*.....*/};
private String[] text_resources_title = {"LLog/..."};
private String[] text_current_page = {"1", "2", /*.....*/};
private String[] text_resources = {"ппервввоеее"/*.....*/};
public static Context ctx;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
static final String TAG = "myLogs";
private static int PagerNumber;
SharedPreferences preferences_wish;
private static int PageFirstReservation;
private static int PageSecondReservation;
SharedPreferences preferences_wish_two;
SharedPreferences preferences_current_page;
private static int numberOfReservation;
Button button_wish_cancel_reserve;
int Reservation_gift;
TextView text_view_current_page;
int current_page;

public CustomSwipeAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
}


public CustomSwipeAdapter() {
      }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
    return image_resources.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
    return (view == (LinearLayout) o);

}

@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout, container, false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    TextView textView_description = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.textViewDescription);
    final TextView text_view_current_page = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_number_page);
    final TextView textView_title = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.textView_title);
    TextView text_hide_cancel_reserve = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.text_hide_cancel_reserve);
    ViewPager view_pager = (ViewPager) item_view.findViewById(R.id.pager_view);
    ImageView imageViewShowPresent = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.reserved_wish_null);
    imageView.setImageResource(image_resources[position]);

    text_view_current_page.setText(text_current_page[position]);
    textView_description.setText(text_resources[position]);
    textView_title.setText(text_resources_title[position]);
    text_hide_cancel_reserve.setText(text_hide_cancel_reserve_array[position]);
    imageViewShowPresent.setImageResource(image_reserved_wish[position]);

    Button button_wish_cancel_reserve = (Button) item_view.findViewById(R.id.button_wish_cancel_reserve);
    button_wish_cancel_reserve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            int current_page = Integer.valueOf(text_view_current_page.getText().toString());
            PagerNumber = current_page;

            Log.d(TAG, "PagerNumber" + PagerNumber);


            if (PageFirstReservation == PagerNumber) {
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("RESERV");
                query.getInBackground((String.valueOf(PageFirstReservation)), new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    public void done(ParseObject gameScore, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {

                            Reservation_gift = gameScore.getInt("reservation");
                        } else {

                        }
                        if (Reservation_gift == 1) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "DO context");

                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
                            Log.d(TAG, "POSLE context");



    CustomSwipeAdapter.SharedPref_Wish();

    container.addView(item_view);
    current_page = Integer.valueOf(text_view_current_page.getText().toString());
    PagerNumber = current_page;


    SharedPreferences preferences_current_page = ctx.getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences_current_page.edit();
    editor.putInt("CurrentPage", PagerNumber);
    editor.apply();
    Log.i(TAG, "CurrentPage " + PagerNumber);
    return item_view;

}


        public static int get_position() {  return PagerNumber; }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);

        }







        public static void Parse_go_to_refresh() {

 ......()содержимое.....

        public static void SharedPref_Wish() {

           ......()содержимое.....
        public void cancel_Reservation_First_or_Second(){

             ......()содержимое.....
```

Comment: Отредактируйте разметку кода в вопросе. Удалите всё лишнее, то что к вопросу не относится. Слишком много кода.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб , дело в том, что я не знаю, что уже и делать: как код ни менял, все не работает, поэтому и выложил весь код Класса. Сейчас отредактировал по-максимуму, кажется.  Можете помочь разобраться?

Comment: получение номера текущей страницы не имеет отношения к адаптеру. Никакого. Адаптер не знает, какая сейчас страница показывается. Вопрос состоит в том, **для чего** используется этот адаптер? Покажите код, где вы пишете `new CustomSwipeAdapter()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вам правильно указали в ответе на предыдущий вопрос вы неверно представляете как ViewPager работает.

1. Вашу задачу проще решить используя фрагменты как разметку каждой страницы ViewPager-а.
2. Получить текущую позицию в ViewPager можно методом getCurrentPosition(); Вы же назначаете её из метода адаптера при формировании разметки страницы. Этот метод может вызываться в разное время, в разном порядке или вообще не вызываться. Оттого и путаница в порядке.

Итого вам надо полностью переделать архитектуру, почитать про ViewPager c фрагментами и понять что в предыдущем вопросе и тут вас направляли по верному пути.

В данный момент вы всё делаете неправильно.